# how the index works in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

What does python do to find -2 items in the list? does iterate through the list?

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(a[-2])

I don't understand how it works.

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `a[len(a) - 2]`, i.e element at index 3

Comment: List in python it isn't linked list but vector/array which size is changing by table doubling algorithm. Indexing operation, like`a[-2]`, has `O(1)` complexity

Answer (score 0):

Python programming language supports negative indexing of arrays, something which is not available in arrays in most other programming languages. This means that the index value of -1 gives the last element, and -2 gives the second last element of an array. The negative indexing starts from where the array ends.

(-) negative index iterates from last element to first element.

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if you do a[-1] it returns last element (5).

if you do a[-2] it returns second last element(4) of the list and so on.